# Custom ArrayAdapter onClick position & row highlight

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, listactivity

I have created a custom ArrayList which is working as it should barring an issue with the onClick. I orginally had the ArrayList highlight the selected row in red when the user clicked on the row. However, I also required the position of that click outside of the ArrayAdapter class.

The only way I could seem to do this is by adding an onClickListener, however this is were the issues began, although this solved my issue of getting the position the user click on, the row highlighting now seems to get overridden.

So basically my issue is allowing both selected rows to be highlighted and position to be passed to a variable outside of the ArrayAdapter class, please see my code below:

Array Adapter Class:

```
public class Shop extends ListActivity
{
    private static class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
    {
        private ArrayList<String> data1, data2, data3, data4;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> data1, ArrayList<String>  data2, ArrayList<String>  data3, ArrayList<String>  data4) 
        {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, data1);
            this.data1 = data1;
            this.data2 = data2;
            this.data3 = data3;
            this.data4 = data4;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data1);
            t1.setText(data1.get(position));
            TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data2);
            t2.setText(data2.get(position));
            TextView t3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data3);
            t3.setText(data3.get(position));
            TextView t4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data4);
            t4.setText(data4.get(position));
            spnCharacters.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Iterator<Integer> iterator = unavailableItem.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                int NotAvailable = iterator.next();
                if(position == NotAvailable)
                {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(170, 170, 170));
                }
            }
            if(unavailableItem.size() == 1)
            {
                if(position == unavailableItem.get(0))
                {
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(170, 170, 170));
                }
            }
            if (position == 0) 
            {
                v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.title_bar);
            }

            v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    currentPositon = position;
                    if(data2.get(currentPositon).equals("0"))
                    {
                        btnSell.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        btnSell.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            });

            return v;
        }
    }

    private void NeedPosition()
    {
        int position = // need ArrayAdapter exact position here
    }
}
```

ArrayAdapter XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

List View XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearButtons"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linerBuyBtns" 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
</ListView>
```

Comment: why don't you use a OnItemClickListener on your listview ?

Comment: I tried using the OnItemClickListener, however was having issues with getting the onClick to fire.

Comment: that probably where you should be looking. adding onclicklistener to all your items is not a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListActvity has its own way to manage cell click.

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

This method will be called when you click on an row of the `ListView`. As you can see the second paramter is the `position` you need

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for had tried using OnItemClickListener previously which was not being fired. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{    
    onClick(...)  
    {    
       convertView.parent().setSelection(position); <---
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with custom listViews and Array adapters..

for me the `android:listSelector` did not work properly so i used `android:Background` instead
where i defined states selected, highlighted etc....At the end to achieve certain visual effects i had to use a combination of both, probably not the best solution but works perfectly.