# ListView and OnClick does not effect the targeted item

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

So I have a custom `ListView` that contains a `CheckBox` as well as a `TextView` when I click the `CheckBox` I want it to cross out the `TextView` my code works for the top item on the list but if I click a `CheckBox` towards the bottom of the list it still crosses out the top `TextView` I am using an onClick approach in the xml I know its not the norm for a `ListView` its just that I didnt know how to handle two different xml elements with a `onListItemClick`

```
public void verify(View view)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        TextView t= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
        Toast.makeText(this, t.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        t.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="verify"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="tasks"
    android:textSize="30px" >
</TextView>
```

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values ) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_task_list, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_task_list, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        textView.setText(values[position]);


        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the XML functionality for onClick, the onClick method will only be called for that specific View. That is, the code generating the onClick callback when you compile will have no chance of knowing that you at runtime generate more of the same View that you wish to handle clicks callbacks from. This is more or less the reason why only the first TextView is dashed, as it is tied to the firstly generated CheckBox, the one and only CheckBox receiving callbacks.

What happens if you change your code to:

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values ) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_task_list, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_task_list, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                textView.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            }
        }
    });

    return rowView;
}
```

If that does not work, then maybe where you apply your adapter:

```
    MobileArrayAdapter mobileArrayAdapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(this,
            R.layout.activity_task_list,yourvalues);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourlist);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
               // fetch TextView from the view 
               textView.setPaintFlags(t.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        }
    });
```

The above seems to have work for: [Custom ArrayAdapter onClick position & row highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641617/custom-arrayadapter-onclick-position-row-highlight)

Comment: So that crosses out the last element regardless of what button was pressed

Comment: True but not a solution